# Microsoft Flow - Excel File Get Rows - Large Excel File

Tags: excel, power-automate

I am a newbie for using Flows with Excel and while Connecting Excel to Flow over SFTP, I get the below error :

```
{{Could not retrieve values. File size above allowed value. File size:15944460, AllowedFileSize (in Bytes): 2000000.}}
```

It says my Excel file stored over the SFTP path is too large hence cannot access the File Table.

I cannot reduce the file size as this is my Source Data.

I need an alternative for accessing the Large Excel File Table into my Flows for Excel - Get Rows.

Comment: Use a different program...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the file size limit can be increased. See the **Message size** part of the document:

[Limits and configuration in Microsoft Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/limits-and-config)